# not able to scroll up and down a page using web driver sampler(J meter) and java

Tags: java, jmeter

I am not able to scroll down a page while using J-meter with WebDriversampler and java.

I have tried 
  javascriptExecutor js=(javascriptExecutor)WDS.browser;
  js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(100,100)");
its not working and even if i tried 
 WDS.browser.executeScript("window.scrollTo(100,100)")
its also not working 
i have imported javascriptExecutor class too in jmeter but still i am not able to execute Scroll functionality

```
javascriptExecutor js=(javascriptExecutor)WDS.browser;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(100,100)");
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax should be:

```
WDS.browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(100,100)')
```

you don't need to import anything or cast the `WDS.browser` to [JavaScriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)

Demo:

[image]

Few things to consider:

1. Check if there is anything suspicious in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging)
2. 100 pixels might be not enough to see the scroll event on modern 4k displays, try giving 1000
3. The scroll event might be too quick, consider surrounding it with i.e. [Thread.sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) functions so you could visually identify the event.
4. Make sure to use the relevant driver (i.e. [ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/) for Chromium and derivatives, [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) for Firefox), etc.
5. Make sure to use up-to-date version of WebDriver Sampler, you can check if your version is actual and install the update if available using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: its not working with java , I have used the same as you have shown me above but still not able to  scroll